# Working hours of a TVL13/50% contract

Tags: phd, germany, visa

I have an offer of a TVL13/50% contract for a PhD in Germany. This corresponds to roughly a 20h work-week. Visa-wise, I must adhere to the following constraint:

> The temporary residence permit entitles the holder to take up employment totaling no more than 120 days or 240 half-days per year, and to take up a student job.

Does a TVL13/50% categorizes as a "student job"? Or is it within the "no more than 240 half-days" requirement?

Comment: Considering holidays, it basically is 240 half-days

Comment: Talk to the immigration office (*Ausländerbehörde*). Since you have a job offer, it might be possible for you to get a proper work visa without too much trouble.

Comment: @cab20 You looked at the rules for student visa. But PhD students are not actually seen as students for most purposes in Germany (exception perhaps if they get a scholarship). This is an aspect that gets lost when translating the German term "Doktorand" to "PhD student". The former does to contain the word "student" (on purpose) and a literal translation would be "Doctoral one". As another example, a few years ago, in some states, PhD students were forbidden from enrolling at their university (not sure if that's still the case). You need a different visa type.

Comment: @DCTLib or "Doctoree", or even "Doctorator" ;)

Comment: @henning I like "doctorator"! I think that I'm using it from now on.

Comment: Thanks for the name "ausländerbehörde", I'm contacting them. @DCTLib What do you mean with "forbidden from enrolling at their university"? In that case, the "doctorators" were under something like a research assistant agreement, but with no formal link to an university/a PhD program?

Comment: Doctorators are all working towards a PhD, regardless of how they are funded. In some (all?) states, they can also enroll as students to get some benefits (at the cost of paying some fees each semester), which can include heavily subsidized food in the "Mensa" (something like a canteen), or a local public transportation ticket. Getting enrolled as a student does not automatically make a Doctorator a student for immigration, taxation, or social security purposes. With a 50% WiMi job, you are in any way primarily an employee of the university.

Comment: The quote you give sounds very much like you are only permitted to get some *part-time* employment. A PhD contract is a full-time employment (with half the working time). I'd bet this is not compatible. (In particular, it is not clear that the working hours in your contract are also 50%, and not only the pay; and you are employed the whole year, not only 240 days.) You certainly should either talk to the immigration office, or better the university first. They have hired PhD students from abroad before, and they will know what type of visa you need (at least, they should know).

Comment: @user151413 "A PhD contract is a full-time employment [...] it is not clear that the working hours in your contract are also 50%, and not only the pay" I'm sorry, but that's just incorrect. If OP has been offered a 50 % TVL position, then that's part time employment. It is impossible to get a contract with full working ours and part-time payment in Germany (and probably everywhere in the world). That would be illegal (because not paying for work is illegal).

Comment: @Roland I've certainly seen contracts which said things along the lines that the employee has to spend his full work time on the PhD work, and the salary amounts to 50% TVL - so the percentage amounts to the pay, not the working hours. (Otherwise, this would mean that postdocs are paid the same as PhD students!) I'm not sure how up to date contracts look like. *But* I am rather sure it is not legal to work another 50% for someone else when you are employed as a PhD student with 50%. (Rather, you can take up a "Nebentätigkeit" up to 8hrs/week like anyone else.)

Comment: These contracts "allow" the employee to work on their PhD. You misunderstood that part of the contract (regarding what it actually stipulated, not regarding its spirit).

Comment: @Roland I'm rather sure I didn't misunderstand. I don't have a current template for such a contract at hand (and if I had, I likely weren't allowed to publish it), but they don't allow the PhD candidate to work another 50% on another job. To put it conversely: Why would I hire a PhD student at the price at which I could get a postdoc?

Comment: @Roland To give an example:  https://www.mpg.de/career/how-do-i-get-supported states that a PhD contract has a working time of 39 hrs/week, and the pay amounts to 50% E13. (And with that, the OP could not claim that he only had a half-day job.)

Comment: @user151413 After reading the German version of that website, what they offer there is not a normal work contract. A "support contract" is very non-standard. It would be interesting to see what exactly is stipulated in these contracts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TVL 13 position (even at 50%) is not a student job. Student jobs have different contracts that are taxed differently and are only available to people currently enrolled as a student (I am not 100%, but still pretty sure, that being enrolled as a PhD student does not count).

A year has about 250 weekdays (= work days), if you take public holidays (depending on how they fall within the year, that will be around 3-6 days) away from that, you are almost at the 240 days of the requirement. If vacation days (30 per year) are not counted, you will have no problem, because then you will be at around 210-215 half work days. But if they are calculated into the 240 days, then you could be just slightly over the 240 days. (This could be actually intended by the law, that you can only have a contract for less than 50%)

**I would strongly suggest you ask someone at the university** if they have any experience with this (HR or the foreign affairs office) - you are probably not the first person from abroad with a similar problem. If it is a problem of just a couple of half-work days to many, you can always ask if they either adjust the position to something like 47%, or if the (at least on paper) adjust the working hours on your contract so that you officially get 50% of the TVL13 salary, but only have to work for 45% of the hours.

Comment: You are employed during your vacation. I expect that vacation days count towards the 240 days.

Comment: I would strongly emphasize the recommendation that cab20 discuss this with the university. Issues involving residence permits are way too important and complicated to depend on (well meaning) people on the internet. For the personnel department this is probably a standard problem which they are more than willing and able to help you with.